# Is there a way to know when actually a server is stopped at EventMachine?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

Using `EM::stop_server` schedules the server to be stopped. How can I know when the server is actually stopped?

```
require 'eventmachine'

class TestServer < EM::Connection
  def post_init
    send_data "Welcome\r\n"
  end
end

class TestClient < EM::Connection
  def receive_data(data)
    puts data
  end
end

Thread.new do
  EM.run { }
end
while !EM.reactor_running? ; end

g = EM::start_server('127.0.0.1', 6667, TestServer)
EM::stop_server(g)
#sleep(1)
EM::connect('127.0.0.1', 6667, TestClient)
sleep
```

Running the above outputs `Welcome`. However if I uncomment `sleep(1)`, nothing is printed.

Is there a way to achieve something similar without using `sleep`? Like using `EM.reactor_running?` to check if EM reactor's has started but to check if a server has been stopped.